# iPhone: How do I add layers to UIView's root layer to display an image with the content property?

Tags: iphone

According to the Mac Dev Center docs, you should be able to set the contents property of a CALayer and have that render automatically. However, I still can't get a simple image to show up by adding a sublayer to the UIView's root later. I've tried multiple different variations; here's what I have so far:

(Note: I know there are other ways of rendering images; for my purposes I'd like to use CALayer's for some of the more complicated stuff I'm going to get into).

(in viewDidDisplay() of the ViewController):

```
 CALayer *theLayer = [CALayer layer];
 [[[self view] layer] addSublayer:theLayer];
 theLayer.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"mypic.png"] CGImage];
 theLayer.contentsRect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 300.0f);
 theLayer.bounds = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 300.0f, 400.0f);
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Ben - you got it. My problem was the contentsRect was way too big - didn't realize it was a unit coordindate space.

Interestingly, the image is placed high and to the left (I only see the lower right 1/4 of it) - I'm having to adjust the position to get the top left corner of the image to sit in the top-right corner of the screen. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to set the `contentsRect` (and if you do, it should be in the unit coordinate space, probably just `CGRectMake(0, 0, 1.0, 1.0).`

You might want to set the `layer`'s `position` property.

Answer (score 5):

You could load the image into a UIImageView, which is decended from UIView and therefore has it's own layer property.

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
imgView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"mypic.png"];

[[[self view] layer] addSublayer:[imgView layer]];
[imgView release];
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two CALayer . This is perfect way to display the image within the CALayer.

```
CALayer *pulseLayer_ = [[CALayer layer] retain];

pulseLayer_.backgroundColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
pulseLayer_.bounds = CGRectMake(0., 0., 80., 80.);
pulseLayer_.cornerRadius = 12.;
pulseLayer_.position = self.view.center;

[self.view.layer addSublayer:pulseLayer_];


CALayer *imageLayer = [CALayer layer];

imageLayer.frame = pulseLayer_.bounds;
imageLayer.cornerRadius = 10.0;
imageLayer.contents = (id) [UIImage imageNamed:@"jacklogo.png"].CGImage;
imageLayer.masksToBounds = YES;

[pulseLayer_ addSublayer:imageLayer];

[pulseLayer_ setNeedsDisplay];
```

I think its make solution to your problem.